# Rigged pants move together?

Tags: rigging

[image: The issue]

Hello, I'm new to rigging models clothing onto models, I can't figure out why both pant legs move together I've followed tutorials on how to rig clothing and did everything they did, but the issue is, the tutorials were for shirts, not pants. I can't find any tutorials for this nor any solutions, if anyone knows why this is happening please let me know, its driving me insane. I've been trying to deal with this for like 3 days now. Thank you

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: You need to know how to rig character manualy https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/introduction-to-rigging Automatic weighting not always works well

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5805" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5805/) @moonboots

Comment: Oh, i see. Do you want to use envelopes or vertex groups??

Comment: When I use vertex groups the knee stays in place while the rest of the leg stretches

Comment: Well it's because legs are separate object, you transfer weight only from top part

Comment: I switched to vertex groups, the stretching doesn't occur anymore however, the one pant leg on the right moves slightly and the right model leg moves freely and through it, also the pant leg on the left side stretches towards the right as if they're connected. and the knee part of the pants don't move at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete this workflow using data transfer I recommend:

Check that armature modifier switched to weight:

[image]

Join this two parts (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>):

[image]

Then apply Data transfer. In unknown reason, it doesn't works with armature even if it first. (maybe, it is because it doesn't grab original mesh from source object)

[image]

Then, finally, fix weights using **weight paint mode**.

[image]

Draw weight with needed bone selected.

Comment: Oh, nevermind just figured it out thanks a lot!

Comment: @Lagnos- If so, don't forget check answer as correct.